# How to convert this native SQL Query to jpa query for my java application

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
SELECT b.books_name,b.books_id FROM BOOKS b JOIN AUTHOR a 
ON b.AUTHOR_ID = a.AUTHOR_ID WHERE a.AUTHOR_NAME='WILLIAM';
```

Comment: Provide your more details for your entities. Like fields names and mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Book and Author entity and establish the mapping.
Since your schema stores the author_id withing the books table... I assume there is many to one mapping here.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOKS")
Class Books {
    @Id
    Integer booksId;
    String booksName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="AUTHOR_ID")
    Author author;
    ... more fields
    public Books(Integer booksId, String booksName) {
        this.booksId = booksId;
        this.booksName = booksName;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="AUTHOR")
Class Author {
    @Id
    String authorId;
    String authorName;
    ... more fields
}
```

JPA query

```
@Query("Select new Books(b.booksId, b.booksName) from Books b where b.author.authorName = 'WILLIAM'")
List<Books> findMatchingBooks();
```

Comment: thnks that was helpful